# Call async function and return result to other function

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, twisted

I'm looking on example at https://alchimia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ but have a issue: How i can return result from other function, which using async API with DB?

It will be something like that:

```
def FindNames():
    result = yield engine.execute(users.select(users.c.name.startswith("D")))
    return result  

def processingResult():
    result = FindNames()
    d_users = yield result.fetchall()
    for user in d_users:
        print "Username: %s" % user[users.c.name]
```

Comment: Just add `yield` before `FindNames()` and use `returnValue(result)` instead of `return result`. btw, `@inlineCallbacks` is not optional here.